# to know if the server page is modified or not

Tags: java, httpclient, httpresponse

I need to check if the server has modified the contents of a page so that I can retrieve that page again. I tried using "Last-Modified" and "ETag" options of header response with httpClient method. But in many pages these values are missing. is there any other way to handle this in JAVA code or any opensource TOOL which does this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to know for sure is to retrieve the page and compare the newer with older version yourself. The Last-Modified header is unreliable as it may not be present, or it could be deliberately spoofed by some sites that do not want dynamic content re-indexed (for whatever reason). The content-length header may  also not be present, so you cann't necessarily rely on this.

When you compare page content you must decide whether you are interested in all changes - or just changes to relevant content areas of the page e.g. excluding  dynamic elements such as menus, date-times etc...

If comparing yourself you could you could probably just check the lengths of the respective documents, for absolute sameness, or else extract the relevant content areas of the page and do a text comparison. To compare similar pages you could also use a "[sim-hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_sensitive_hashing)", whereby the hash values for similar data are close to each other (as opposed to the usual sparse hashing).

Answer (score 0):

The If-Modified-Since header will return HTTP 304 if the entity has not been modified, and will return the new entity if it has been modified since the date specified in the header.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.25

Comment: If-Modified-Since header is used with last-modified date. my question is, if server doesn't provide last-modified time with response then how to check that page is not modified???

Answer (score 0):

Compare two Content-length headers? It's is quite likely that it will not be exactly the same if the page is modified in some way. Not the perfect solution, but good enough for practical purposes considered.

Comment: loskit: this might be one of the easy solution but unfortunately i have some web-sites which doesn't give content-length also as part of response. what to do??? ex:google, http://philips.meteo-graphics.com